# Where can I obtain the Android 1.5 and 1.6 Calendar Source code?

Tags: android, calendar, android-source

Where can I obtain the Android 1.5 and 1.6 Calendar Source code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The source code for the entire [Calendar application](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar) is available at the Android Open Source Project.

Answer (score 6):

Android source is moved from git.kernel.org to googlesource so here is [new link of calendar source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Calendar](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/provider/Calendar.java&q=package:android%20Calendar.java&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc) provider source code in the Android repository. As far as the actual Calendar activity, I'm not sure if that is Open Sourced.

Answer (score 0):

A custom calendar is available here with source code.
http://droidwalk.blogspot.in/